# Populating Input Options based selection

Tags: jquery, html, input

Im trying to find the best method for creating a number of input menus that will auto populate based upon there selections. 
The problem I have is there quite a few options. There will be 4 dropdowns. Each dropdown will have 2 options.

I was looking at the following example. Though this method work the amount of code would be hefty >>
http://devingredients.com/2011/05/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-with-jquery/

Does anyone know the best method for achieving this ??

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

This could be easily done with some generic helper functions.

For example, instead of manually providing the raw HTML for each value you could write a function that clears and populates the `<select>` element according to a single value that is passed.

In preparation, you'll want to create an object containing the values of the first `<select>` as indexes to the list of second `<select>`.  Something like this -

```
var beverages = {
 'wine' : ['Red','White'],
 'beer' : ['dark','pale'],
 'juice': ['mango','grapefruit']
};
```

Now we know that `beverages['beer'][0]` will get us a cold bottle of beer.

From here we can write a more generic function to help us with the HTML manipulations...

```
function populateSelect(category){
  // remove all existing options.
  $("#secondSelection").find('option').remove(); 
  $.each(beverages[category],function(index,elem){
    // for each item in beverages[category],
    // we add an option to the <select>.
     $("#secondSelection").append('<option>'+elem+'</option>');
  });
}
```

You would call this function like this -

```
populateSelect($("#firstSelection").val());
```

The markup you'd have to have would be something like this -

```
<select id="firstSelection">
  <option value='beer'>Beer</option>
  <option value='wine'>Wine</option>
  <option value='juice'>Juice</option>
</select>
<select id="secondSelection">
  <option>Choose a Category</option>
</select>
```

---

For more complex structures like the ones you described, you could just nest more options in the original object and it's arrays...

Comment: Thanks for the update. However im just trying to test it all out but the jquery seems to fail. Any ideas http://jsfiddle.net/Y3wa5/3/

Comment: Yes, there was a slight error in my code.  But look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3wa5/10/) - that is how you are supposed to implement this.  You still have to attach an `.on('change')` listener...

Comment: You should think about making your first `<option>` element something like `--Choose one--` so that you can be sure the `change` event will be fired.

Comment: Thats working great. I tried adding an additional input but as it stands it doesnt populate correctly http://jsfiddle.net/Y3wa5/16/

Comment: No - you misunderstood me.  What I meant is that the first option on the first selection (in my case the selection with `beer`,`wine`...) would be `--choose one--` - [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3wa5/17/)

Comment: yep i got that bit :-) I just wanted to find a way to link in a 3rd drop down.

Comment: any ideas on how to link it together for 3 input boxes?